# If you come to me, you may never want to leave

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Inside me lies  a pantheon of countless wisdom and knowledge,
> Though you may possess most of it in your hand, I'll acknowledge.
>
> I bring you stories of lives born false and true,
> So many of them will make you feel born anew.
>
> Now stories aren't just all I contain,
> Of advice, or instruction, these I obtain.
>
> To many I am loved, to some I am hated,
> A child, especially, will become educated.
>
> Bringing feelings of love, laughter and pain,
> Or of duty, pleasure, all these you can gain.
>
> Open to many, the forgetful and careless I detest,
> Keepers who protect me, they'll reject my guests.

What Am I?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you are:

> **A Library**

I might have initially guessed you are:

> A book, but the initial letters of each line tell me it isn't so!

Inside me lies a pantheon of countless wisdom and knowledge,
Though you may possess most of it in your hand, I'll acknowledge.

> Libraries have a lot of books containing information, though most of it is also accessible via our mobile phones

I bring you stories of lives born false and true,
So many of them will make you feel born anew.

> Fiction and biographies, both of which can inspire

Now stories aren't just all I contain,
Of advice, or instruction, these I obtain.

> The non-fiction section of libraries contain books about skills and knowledge

To many I am loved, to some I am hated,

> Reading enthusiasts love a trip to the library, and this also explains the title
>
>  However, some find the library boring (e.g. in a school that has a library period)

A child, especially, will become educated.

> As above, books can teach us

Bringing feelings of love, laughter and pain,
Or of duty, pleasure, all these you can gain.

> Different genres of books tick these boxes - romances, humour, tragedies, etc.

Open to many, the forgetful and careless I detest,
Keepers who protect me, they'll reject my guests.

> Many libraries are public libraries
>  Librarians hate those who lose books, damage, defile, or misplace them

Comment: This is correct of course, but there's one secret clue I'd like for you to include if you can find it.

Comment: Added it in the second spoiler block, @Joe-You-Know - hope that's what you meant!

Comment: That is precisely what I meant. Great job

Comment: By the way, very often, puzzles like these have an actual (or close enough) answer of "a mobile phone", I like the way you subverted it in your second line.

Comment: I was afraid that it would be too broad if I didn't narrow it down.